# C0G vs polypropylene capacitors in signal filtering

Tags: capacitor, instrumentation-amplifier, dielectric

Can anybody give me a comprehensive pros and cons list or explanation about the differences between C0G (NP0) ceramic and polypropylene capacitors?

I would like to use them in signal filtering and amplification (biomedical measurements.)

Comment: what behavioral differences have your seen in your studies?

Comment: Polypropylene has a low melting point and cannot be used to manufacture surface mount capacitors. They have to be leaded. So if you plan to use only SMDs, the question should be about SMD film caps (PPS for example) vs C0G instead.

Comment: Some data: http://www.kemet.com/Lists/TechnicalArticles/Attachments/53/2008-03%20Advances%20in%20Class-I%20C0G%20MLCC%20and%20SMD%20Film%20Capacitors.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Take this as a not-so-comprehensive comparison:

1. For C0G (NP0) capacitors, you only have a choice of less than 0.5 uF capacitors, There are not many higher-capacity C0G capacitors, and with an increase in capacitance the price increases accordingly. but with polypropylene capacitors, you have a wider choice higher capacitance and voltage.
2. Polypropylene capacitors are available chiefly as leaded components. while you have the chance to find ceramic capacitors in different SMD packages.
3. Both types have quite linear frequency and voltage responses, but this is just a general term and for a specific application, characteristics of parts must be analyzed.

Overall if we put spacing problems aside I would choose polypropylene capacitors for highers capacitance and C0G ones for lower capacitance.